# Convert Excel RTD library to Excel-DNA while retaining =RTD( interface (64 bit Excel)

Tags: excel-dna

I have written an IRTDServer in C# and it works fine.

I'd like to convert the code to use Excel DNA (for various reasons, but the most important being that I'd like to have multiple addins loaded each in their own appdomain).

However, in the short term, I'd like to preserve the "old" way of calling, i.e. 
    =RTD("ProgId",,"MyCoolFunction","Arg1").

I'm using this sample project to get started with:

https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/RtdClocks/RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer

I have it working so that I can use =dnaRtdClock_ExcelRtdServer() in Excel and it gives me time updates every few seconds.

1. Is it going to be possible to call it via =RTD(" ...
2. If so, am I correct that the function to enter into Excel would be =RTD("RtdClock.ClockServer",,"dummy/ignored").
3. And then mainly:

**What do I need to do to be able to call that same function via =RTD("RtdClock.ClockServer",,"dummy/ignored")**

I guess I should also ask a fourth question:

If I am able to successfully access the IRTDServer via the =RTD( function call, will Excel/Excel-DNA be loading the implementing DLL into the FullyTrustedSandbox or the DefaultDomain? [after all, the whole reason I'm doing this conversion to Excel DNA is to get the AppDomain feature].

Things I've tried:

1. I added a GUID to RTDClockServer project.
2. I ran %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer.dll /codebase.  Initially it complained about ExcelDna.Integration being missing.   So I changed the reference to that package to be CopyLocal=True.
3. I checked the registry.  It does have all the COM registration entries that I would expect from registering an RTD server.
4. I've tried adding =RTD("RtdClock.ClockServerRTD",,) as  function call.  I see that it does load my DLL and hits a break point, but ONLY the ServerTerminate breakpoint (so, not the ServerStart for example).  I also see that the AppDomain in this case is DefaultDomain, not the "FullyTrustedSandBox: ..."
5. I've tried running c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 against the DLL, against all of the *.xll files in the following directory: [note: I started with the RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64-packed.xll and RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64.xlls as they seemed most logical too me.]  These consistently fail silently from the command line, but in the EventViewer I see an error:

   Application: regsvr32.exe
   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
      at ExcelDna.Integration.RunMacroSynchronization.Register()
      at ExcelDna.Integration.SynchronizationWindow..ctor()
      at ExcelDna.Integration.SynchronizationManager.Install()
      at ExcelDna.Integration.DnaLibrary.Initialize()
      at ExcelDna.Integration.DnaLibrary.InitializeRootLibrary(System.String)

```
     Directory of C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ExcelDna-Samples\RtdClocks\RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer\bin\Debug

    02/01/2020  10:38    <DIR>          .
    02/01/2020  10:38    <DIR>          ..
    02/01/2020  10:38           629,248 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn-packed.xll
    02/01/2020  08:31               939 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn.dna
    09/09/2015  22:49           751,104 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn.xll
    02/01/2020  10:38           539,136 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64-packed.xll
    02/01/2020  08:31               939 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64.dna
    09/09/2015  22:49           660,992 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64.xll
    02/01/2020  10:38             6,144 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer.dll
    02/01/2020  10:38            17,920 RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer.pdb
```

[image]

```
namespace RtdClock_ExcelRtdServer
{
    [Guid("2838E6F0-B2CA-4FC9-A9AF-7F834CBC595C")]
    [ComVisible(true)]                   // Required since the default template puts [assembly:ComVisible(false)] in the AssemblyInfo.cs
    [ProgId(RtdClockServer.ServerProgId)]     //  If ProgId is not specified, change the XlCall.RTD call in the wrapper to use namespace + type name (the default ProgId)
    public class RtdClockServer : ExcelRtdServer  
    {
        public const string ServerProgId = "RtdClock.ClockServer";

        // Using a System.Threading.Time which invokes the callback on a ThreadPool thread 
        // (normally that would be dangerous for an RTD server, but ExcelRtdServer is thread-safe)
        Timer _timer;
        List<Topic> _topics;

        protected override bool ServerStart()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(timer_tick, null, 0, 1000);
            _topics = new List<Topic>();
            return true;
        }
```

Note: 
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
Microsoft Excel for Office 365 Version 1911 Build 12228.20364 Click-to-Run Monthly Channel

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to run `RegSvr32.exe RtdClock-ExcelRtdServer-AddIn64-packed.xll` or something similar, to register the .xll file as the COM library serving up the RTD server. Doing `Regasm.exe` on the .dll file makes a mess, causing the COM registration to go against mscorlib which hosts the .dll in the default AppDomain as you see.

Comment: Thanks @Govert.  

I tried Regsvr32 on the unpacked and it reported success via dialog.  But no new entries in Registry.   I tried Regsv32 on the _packed_ and it reported success via dialog AND I see registry entries, plus when I reference the function via RTD in Excel I do see some signs of life, I can attach debugger and I see the ExcelRtdServer getting instantiated.  And I can see that the construction is happening in the FullyTrustedSandbox - yay!  But ...

Comment: ... then only ServerTerminate called.  (Not ServerStart) 

In VisualStudio output window I see: 

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in ExcelDna.Integration.dll ExcelDna.Integration 
Warning: 1 : SynchonizationManager could not be installed - probably running in HPC host or Regsvr32.exe – 

(Note, when I say ServerStart, I'm referring to the override ServerStart - I'm not sure if the underlying IRTDServer.ServerStart(callback) is being called - I'm running against the nuget package not again the ExcelDna codebase directly at present.)

Comment: Is this in a context where the same RTD server and add-in works fine via wrapper functions? If not, you should backtrack to a working example. You might then try to change the wrapper to call `XlCall.Excel(xlCall.xlfRtd,...)` instead of `XlCall.RTD`.

Comment: It is in a working example - although actually the working example I used for the above was my large complex project [which now works great now thanks to the AppDomain wizardry in ExcelDNA - thanks for that!], not the simple RTD clocks.  I'll try it with the RTD clocks again but first time round I did try regsvr32 on the clocks project (as above).   Do you reckon that "regsvr32" warning mentioned in previous comment is indicative of a show-stopper of some sort, or are you fairly confident I should be able to acheive my original objective?